# How to display BindingResult errors on Foundation modal popup with form inputs

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, zurb-foundation

I am working with spring controllers and thymeleaf views for a website. 
I have a html page which displays all the user details. Hence, On click of a "edit" button I pop-up a modal (foundation) which contains a form with all the editable fields of the user. On submit a spring controller is queried to validate the input fields and eventually save the updates.

However, in case of validation errors I want to reload the page from the  controller, with the modal displayed with all the errors.

How can I verify if a form has errors, and eventually popup the modal?

Here the controller.

```
    @PostMapping(path="/admin/associati/modifica")
    public String editAssociato(final HttpServletRequest request,  @ModelAttribute("associato") @Valid User associato, 
                BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Principal principal, Model model) {        
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // DO STUFF
            return "associati/associati_nuovo";
        }       
        return "redirect:/admin/associati";
}
```

And here the modal:

```html
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
 
    <form th:object="${associato}" th:action="@{/admin/associati/nuovo}" method="post">
 
        <div class="profile_fields_row">
            <h4>Nome</h4>
            <input type="text" name="nome" th:field="*{nome}">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')}" th:errors="*{nome}" th:text="#{NotNull.user.firstName}"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="profile_fields_row">
            <h4>Cognome</h4>
            <input type="text" name="cognome" th:field="*{cognome}">
            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cognome')}" th:errors="*{cognome}" th:text="#{NotNull.user.lastName}"></span>
        </div>
        
        ... OTHER FIELDS ...
 
 <div style="text-align: right;">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Salva">
            <a class="button minimal no_icon" href="#">Annulla</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly you should be annotating your POJOs to ensure validity of the fields; then you should be adjusting controller code accordingly. Finally you should be redirecting to the same thymeleaf view and get the binding errors and display them accordingly. All of these can be found in this example. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/10/validation-thymeleaf-spring.html

Comment: I am afraid you didn't get my question. I know how to handle the Validation process. Normally when the controller finds errors, it redirects to the html page with the form submitted and the error messages are displayed. 

However in my case, the form is displayed in a reveal-modal on button click. This means that, when the controller redirects to the html page, the reveal-modal (with the form inside) is not loaded and the error messages cannot be visualised.

Comment: I get it perfectly. You should be doing that and redirect to your page where you can check if there is a validity error then you can open up modal with the desired values and show the output of your binding errors. You can check if there is validity errors on page load with thymeleaf inline JS processing and open the modal programmaticaly.

Comment: I know hot to load programmatically the modal, but I don't know hot to check if there is validity errors on page load. Could you give an example?